# How Scroll Item Listview With Seekbar in Eclipse

Tags: android

How Scroll Item Listview With Seekbar in Eclipse.
or
If seelbar that is how the situation is changing with the music player

Comment: please provide a piece of your code with your tries to fix the issue

Comment: first you get number listiview items(Size) and set size of seekbar.when scroll you seekbar you update your listview adapter....

Comment: How Scroll Too much text or Item Listview With Seekbar.
Also seekbar
Changing the position of the audio file playback.

Like this
http://ooza.ir/out.gif